# Horizontally concatenating column vectors represented by similar variable names

Tags: matlab, loops

Is there a quick way in Matlab to code the following:

`[SmallA41./SmallA42, SmallA51./SmallA52, SmallA61./SmallA62, ..., SmallA201./SmallA202]`

where `SmallA` is common to all variables, the 'numbers' range from `4` to `20`, and each variable name of the form `SmallA__` is a `101 x 1` vector?

I have been trying `horzcat`, but don't know how to loop over the variable names.

Thanks!

Comment: This could help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/275986

Comment: The correct answer is "use arrays not a bunch of variables". But not knowing the circumstances in which you acquired this code, that may not be possible.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I agree with your comment about using arrays, but I just could not do that in this circumstance. I am working on a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you *really* need to stop relying on variable names so let's first convert those variables into a cell array where each element contains your 100 x 1 vector.

```
SmallA1 = rand(100,1);
SmallA2 = rand(100,1);
SmallA3 = rand(100,1);
SmallA4 = rand(100,1);

vars = whos('SmallA*');

% Borrowing the idea from the answers below
tmp = [tempname, '.mat'];
save(tmp, vars.name);
data = load(tmp, '-mat');

indices = str2double(regexp({vars.name}, '(?<=SmallA)\d', 'match', 'once'));

A = cell(size(vars));
for k = 1:numel(vars)
    A{indices(k)} = data.(vars(k).name);
end
```

Now `A` is an N-element cell array containing your data where the index of each element corresponds to the number portion of your previous variable names.

Now to do what you want, you can simply use the indexing and matrix division.

For the simply case I have presented this will be

```
result = cat(2, A{1:2:end}) ./ cat(2, A{2:2:end});
```

For the exact scenario you have posted, this would translate to:

```
result = cat(2, A{41:10:end}) ./ cat(2, A{42:10:end});
```

Since all of your SmallA* values are 100x1 vectors, you could instead store the results in a 100 x N array where each column represents the value contained by each of your variables.

```
A = cat(2, A{:});
```

And then perform the division you want the following way:

```
result = A(:,41:10:end) ./ A(:,42:10:end);
```

Then with these changes you can focus on the actual math and stop worrying about how to parse variable names, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A possible **not exactly elegant** solution but which allows **not using `eval`** could be:

- identify the varaibles of interest
- store these variables in a dummy `.mat` file
- read the variables stored in the dummy `.mat` file into a struct
- access to the fields of the struct by dinamically generating the namesof the fields itself

The dummy `.mat` could by deleted at the end of the script.

```
% Define the input arrays
SmallA4=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA5=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA6=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA7=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA8=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA9=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA10=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA11=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA12=randi(10,3,1);;
SmallA13=randi(10,3,1);;
Small13=randi(10,3,1);;
% Get the names of the varaibles
lv=who('SmallA*')
% Save the desired variables in a dummy ".mat" file
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(tempname);
save([name '.mat'],lv{:})
% Load the varaible stored in the dummy ".mat" file in a struct
lv_s=load([name '.mat'])
% Build the target matrix by dinamically creating the names of the fields
m=[];
for i=4:2:13
   m=[m,lv_s.(['SmallA' num2str(i)])./lv_s.(['SmallA' num2str(i+1)])]
end
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla

Comment: Whoever decides to use `eval` is a `p'tak`. You get a vote from me because you didn't use it. +1.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
for kk = 4:20
    y(:,kk-3) = horzcat(eval(['SmallA' num2str(kk) '1'])./eval(['SmallA' num2str(kk) '2']));
end
```